# Does the full backup truncate transaction log?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008, backup-restoration, transaction-log

Does the transaction log get truncated when I take a full backup using command

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks
    TO Adventurewks
GO
```

Or do I have to take a log backup separately?

```
BACKUP LOG AdventureWorks
   TO Adventurewks;
GO
```

Or is the log backup just for a point-in-time restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A log backup is needed to truncate the logs.

Here is an article that contains some information on this, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx